# Use .net framework from a cloud based IDE (cloud9, koding, etc)

Tags: .net, cloud9-ide

Is it possible to use .net in a cloud based IDE?  On a PC I must download the framework, but that's not possible in a cloud based IDE.

Can I just upload all the DLLs and reference them?

Or, if .net is now open source, can I just copy every single .cs file into my solution in the cloud IDE?

Answer (score 0):

Cloud9 gives you an Ubuntu virtual machine with root access. I'm not sure if it's possible to use .net on Ubuntu but if it is you can use it with Cloud9.

Comment: as long as your ok with ".net" == "mono" then you should be good.

Comment: "virtual machine with root access."  Does this mean I can actually see the desktop too? ...and could even use the VM for personal use non related to programming?